# Reuse the obstacle in AndEngine game

Tags: android

i am having problem in making a game using And Engine..its a 2 car game in which two obstacle are falling from the top of the screen and when one reaches to a height of car*4 the second obstacle starts falling.and when first obstacle reach to maximum height of Camera resets its position..and when second obstacle reach to the height of car*4 then again first obstacle start falling from top of the screen here is some code..

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 rt_left_obstacle1=new Rectangle(0,0,20,20,MainActivity.getSharedInstance().getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                 rt_left_obstacle2=new Rectangle(0,0,20,20,MainActivity.getSharedInstance().getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                 rt_left_obstacle1.setPosition((mCamera.getWidth()/5)/2,0);
                  rt_left_obstacle2.setPosition((mCamera.getWidth()/5)/2,-mCamera.getHeight());  
                 rt_left_obstacle1.setColor(1,0,0);
                    rt_left_obstacle2.setColor(1,0,0);
                  for(int i=100;i<=mCamera.getHeight();i=i+100){
                     rt_left_obstacle1.registerEntityModifier(new MoveYModifier(3,rt_left_obstacle1.getY(),mCamera.getHeight()));
                     if(i==left_car.getHeight()*4){
                         rt_left_obstacle2.registerEntityModifier(new MoveYModifier(2,rt_left_obstacle2.getY(),mCamera.getHeight())); 

                     }
                     if(i==mCamera.getHeight()){
                          rt_left_obstacle1.setPosition((mCamera.getWidth()/5)/2,0);

                     }
                         if(rt_left_obstacle2.getY()==mCamera.getHeight()){
                          rt_left_obstacle2.setPosition((mCamera.getWidth()/5)/2,-mCamera.getHeight());  
                     }

            }

            }
        }, 2000,200);
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What is your question exactly?

Comment: there are two obstacle i want that these two obstacle falling one after another from the top of the screen..

Answer (score 0):

Use GenericPool class from andengine. it will create sprites (in ur case say it obstacles) when ur r done with sprites it will recycles sprites to pool when u want to use sprites again u will simply get it from pool.. and u have not to create sprites again and again... google GenericPool u will found lots of examples and tutorials... :)